# Jquery - Slide to a certain position in a div with overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, overflow

I have many spans in a div with `overflow:hidden;` Because the div width is fixed, at first only 5 spans are visible. On button click, how can I slide to a certain span making it visible?

[**LIVE JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LdzTH/)

JQUERY

```
$("#gobtn").click(function (e)  {
    $("span.selected").removeClass('selected');
    var s = $('#nr').val();
    $("#c" + s).addClass('selected');
  //$("#c" + s).??? 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='circles'>
        <span id='c1'>1</span>  
        <span id='c2'>2</span>
        <span id='c3'>3</span>
        <span id='c4'>4</span> 
        <span id='c5'>5</span>  
        <span id='c6'>6</span>  
        <span id='c7'>7</span>
        <span id='c8'>8</span> 
        <span id='c9'>9</span>  
        <span id='c10'>10</span> 
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br/>
Go to circle nr. <input id='nr' type="text" /> 
<input type='button' id='gobtn'  value='go!'>
```

CSS

```
span {
    border: solid 1px Silver;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.circles {
    width:9000px;
}
.container {
    width:300px;
    display:block;    
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 2px #eee;
    padding:10px;
}
.selected
{
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `position: relative` to the `circles` class. And set the `left` property with an `animate` method.

I made one. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LdzTH/2/). You can improve this as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Animate the left margin of the `circles` class in the `click` function:

```
$("#gobtn").click(function (e)  {
    $("span.selected").removeClass('selected');
    var s = $('#nr').val();
    $("#c" + s).addClass('selected');

    $(".circles").animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + (parseInt(s-1) * 40) + 'px'
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LdzTH/15/

Still needs fine tuned to get the numbers to exactly where you want them, i.e. should selected always be in the middle.